# What does a well-posed problem imply?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

A well-posed problem in the sense of Hadamard states that:

- A solution exists
- The solution is unique
- The solution's behavior changes continuously with the initial conditions.

Now in order to prove this kind of results there are several techniques that are used separately or in combination with each other.

For example, using energy estimates, using $C^{0}$ semigroups, proving the existence and uniqueness of a Green function,etc.

My question is: How much can be said if we start with a well-posed problem:

Can we guarantee that a Green function exist and is unique?

Is there always an operator $A$ that generates a $C_{0}$ semigroup?

Is there always an energy inequality giving the correct control so if one started with those then one will be able to prove at least part of the well-possessedness?

I am more familiar with hyperbolic PDE but I am interested in this kind of converses in elliptic and parabolic problems also if there are any result available.

For the sake of concreteness I am most interested in the problem:
$\Box_{g}\phi=0$ 
where $\Box_{g}$ is the wave operator in a Lorentzian manifold.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not looking for a concrete answer to that abstract question. If point evaluations are continuous linear functionals, then there are various tools of Functional Analysis--depending on the space--to represent such pointwise evaluation functionals as integrals. Then you have to start studying the integral expressions to relate them back to the differential equation.

Comment: To my understanding you shouldn't expect to see a Green's function in a nonlinear problem, because their use is essentially a kind of generalized superposition principle. My impression is similar with semigroup theory. (In particular, I am more familiar with semigroup theory from the standpoint of stochastic problems, where it allows us to write stochastic representations of solutions to certain PDE...all of which are linear).